# Is the pharmaceutical industry the most profitable business in the United States?

Tags: united-states, economics, pharmaceutical, corporate-finance, medications

The Russia Today article [Pharmageddon: America’s bitter pill](http://rt.com/news/us-prescription-drugs-abuse-715/) claims

> **The pharmaceutical industry remains the most profitable business in the US**. More success and financial gain for the companies will always remain possible as long as more Americans are encouraged to take drugs.

I find this pretty hard to believe, so is it?

Comment: Are we talking only about profits that are then paid to the investors?  Or also profits that are then used for research into new drugs?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depends on how you define "profitable". But either way it's not the top one.

I couldn't find more recent data, but in 2008 pharmaceutical industry wasn't the most profitable, although it was high in various rankings, not so high in others ([source CNN](http://money.cnn.com/magazines/fortune/fortune500/2008/performers/industries/profits/)):

### Profit as percentage of revenue

1. Network and Other Communications Equipment  28.8%
2. Mining, Crude-Oil Production    23.8%
3. **Pharmaceuticals   15.8%**
4. Medical Products and Equipment  15.2%
5. Oil and Gas Equipment, Services 13.7%
6. Commercial Banks    12.6%
7. Railroads   12.4%
8. Entertainment   12.4%
9. Insurance: Life, Health (stock) 10.6%
10. Household and Personal Products 10.2%

### Profit as percentage of assets

1. Network and Other Communications Equipment  13.9%
2. Medical Products and Equipment  12.1%
3. Oil and Gas Equipment, Services 11.0%
4. Household and Personal Products 10.4%
5. Food Services   10.4%
6. **Pharmaceuticals   9.1%**
7. Specialty Retailers 8.5%
8. Wholesalers: Diversified    8.4%
9. Petroleum Refining  8.3%
10. Mining, Crude-Oil Production    7.8%

### Revenue per $ of asset

1. Wholesalers: Health Care    3.91
2. Food and Drug Stores    2.78
3. Wholesalers: Electronics and Office Equipment   2.63
4. Automotive Retailing, Services  2.62
5. Wholesalers: Diversified    2.10
6. Specialty Retailers 2.03
7. Engineering, Construction   1.93
8. Petroleum Refining  1.90
9. Health Care: Pharmacy and Other Services    1.78
10. Food Production 1.75

...

40 .    **Pharmaceuticals   0.52**

Comment: just to add, total profit of all Pharmaceuticals in the fortune 1000 from your source is ~$40,000 million, which is less than just Exxon Mobile.

Comment: how about gross profits?